# Custom type in .d.ts file

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to add a property to the Request interface of Express.

This works :

```js
declare namespace Express {
    export interface Request {
        user?: string;
    }
}
```

This doesn't :

```js
import { UserCursor } from "./util/userCursor"; // UserCursor is a class
declare namespace Express {
    export interface Request {
        user?: UserCursor;
    }
}
```

Error given in all the files that make use of `req.user`, but not in the file above:

```
Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>'.
```

Why? How to attribute the type `UserCursor` to `Express.Request.user`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that I know that `tsc` won't take files which contain `import/export` at the scope with `declare` keyword as typing definition that's why your above code doesn't work.

But you could `import` at the lower level inside `declare` scope though which means following code would work:

```js
declare namespace Express {
  export interface Request {
    user?: import("./util/userCursor").UserCursor;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, one of the answers to this question is the following:

```js
import { UserCursor } from "./util/userCursor";
declare global {
    namespace Express {
        export interface Request {
            user?: UserCursor;
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason, wrapping everything in `declare global` seems to do the job. tmhao2005's answer looks better though, and I heard it isn't really good practice.